# My custom View doesn't save its state

Tags: android

I have a custom View called MyView that inflates its content from XML layout. In the XML I have a TextView whose id is "text". I have 2 MyViews in my Activity. So there are 2 Views with id "text". Which causes problems with Android's implementation of onSaveInstanceState - only one of the TextView's is saved. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to change the ID of one of your "text" Views.

Comment: Well, you state in your question that you have two different views which have the ID "text". You need to change one of those to have a different ID. Without looking at your code to know how you've implemented things, I cannot be any more specific than that.

Comment: I have one MyView class that loads layout from myview.xml. Inside myview.xml there is a TextView with id="text". In activity.xml I have 2 MyViews. Each of them will load its contents from myview.xml. So if I chenge the id in myview.xml, _both_ of my MyViews will have a TextView with the new id.

Comment: Ahhh, OK. I now understand the problem. The default implementation of onSaveInstanceState will do the work for you, but is dependent on each view in the hierarchy having a unique ID within the hierarchy. If you have duplicate IDs then you'll need to override onSavedInstanceState to manage the persistence of your Activity state. You'll need to handle the state restoration in onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I don't liked the idea of change Ids. After a lot of research I found a solution for my problem overriding the onAttachedToWindow() and changing the object value only inside it, instead of to change in onRestoreInstanceState. I hope it helps.

```
@Override
protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState(){
    bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable("instanceState", super.onSaveInstanceState());
    bundle.putString("Text", txt_edit.getText().toString());
    return bundle;

}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    if (state instanceof Bundle) {
          bundle = (Bundle) state;

          state = bundle.getParcelable("instanceState");
    }
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
}

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    if (bundle != null){
        txt_edit.setText(bundle.getString("Text"));
    }

    super.onAttachedToWindow();
}
```